# TFS user sees all files locked even though they are not

Tags: tfs

I set up an external contractor to use TFS but when he connects he sees each and every file as locked, even though only one or two are locked. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/tags: A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.

Comment: How is he determining that things are locked?  Can you post a screenshot to clarify?

Comment: Which version of tfs?